# Converting an opacity map into mesh

Tags: mesh, sculpting

Using Substance Painter I've been using different textures to mask out parts of a complex form. I would love it if there was a way to convert the geometry with the opacity map into a new mesh that omits the masked out areas. Anyone idea of how to do this in Blender?

Comment: You can convert filled 2d curves to mesh and you can make filled curves of svg files. Or you can use a displace modifier on a high resolution plane, apply it then delete the higher or lower ares easily.

Comment: I love the displace modifier idea. Follow up question, is there a short hand way of selecting all of the higher or lower areas other than manually doing it?

Comment: In wireframe view, in side vew, use the border selection tool.